# Favicon doesn't display in IE and Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, favicon

I'm really puzzled about why my favicon doesn't show up in either IE9 or Chrome.  It does show in Firefox though.  I've used favicons before and never had such troubles, and my code is quite trivial:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

The file favicon.ico I use is directly taken from Wikipedia (for testing purpose to be sure it's not a faulty ICO file) and put in the same folder as the HTML file.  I tried clearing the browser's caches and restarting them, but nothing works.  Also, this is not on a web server, I open the HTMLs directly from the file system.

Answer (score 1):

Also add another tag to make it like this for increased browser coverage:

```
<LINK REL="icon" HREF="favicon.ico" TYPE="image/x-icon">
<LINK REL="shortcut icon" HREF="favicon.ico" TYPE="image/x-icon">
```

Answer (score 0):

I get favicons to work in Chrome with

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/myapp/img/favicon.ico" />
</head>
</body>
```

Maybe strip the `TYPE` attribute?

Comment: I tried using an absolute path and stipping the type attribute, but nothing helps... maybe something's wrong with the computer.  Or caching behavior of browsers wrt favicons is too weird to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (with slash):

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

This should work

Comment: In this form, this is wrong. It only works with **slash** at the beginning, if the OP has his/her favicon in the public **root**. Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon: *"file name and a location can be specified for any Web site directory"*. So theoretically, the regular `favicon.ico` is the same as `./favicon.ico`, which means the browser should look for the favicon.ico file in the current directory (which can also be a subdirectory relative to the root). The `/favicon.ico` form means that the browser should look for the `favicon.ico` file in the public root.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your history.

Hit the file directly first in your browser address bar.

Then remove your whole line since by default it looks at the root for that file.

Comment: OP says "this is not on a web server, I open the HTMLs directly from the file system" - so, uh, what absolute path does "/favicon.ico" resolve to in the context of a file:// address?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it's an actual icon file and not a bmp/jpg/png saved as .ico,

use this if it helps:

http://www.favicon.cc/